# Add class and keep it when and after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, navbar

i try to change the backgoundcolor of a navbar link (when it's active) when user click on it.
I get the last element in a URL, it's index.html in 
file:///home/mery/Alterway/ign-portail/custom/themes/portail/static-builder/__public/styleguide/index.html and i compare it with the href of the  clicked.
when i click on the , the page is refreshed and i see nothing ! 
This is my code :

```
//Active navbar link
var get_url = function (){
    $('.nav-item .nav-link').click(function (e) {
        var current = location.pathname;
        console.log("autre res : ",
        $('.nav-item .nav-link').attr('href').indexOf(current));
        // // $('.nav-item .nav-link').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.attr('href') == window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)){
            // if($this.attr('href') !== -1){
                console.log("this element", $this);
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
        // })
    });
}
```

My HTML code :

```
{% if navItems %}
<ul class="navbar-nav{% if navLeft %} navbar-nav--left{% endif %}{% if navPortails %} navbar-nav--portails{% endif %}">
    {% for item in navItems %}
    <li class="nav-item{% if item.isActive %} is-active{% endif %}">
        {% if item.hasChild %}
            <button class="nav-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse-{{ loop.index0 }}" aria-controls="nav-collapse-{{ loop.index0 }}" aria-expanded="false">{{ item.text }}{% if item.isActive %} <span class="sr-only">(page courante)</span>{% endif %}</button>

            <div class="collapse nav-collapse" id="nav-collapse-{{ loop.index0 }}">
                <div class="nav-collapse-inner">
                    {% include "navbar-nav__submenu.twig" with { 'navItems': item.hasChild } %}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ item.link }}"{% if item.target %} target="{{ item.target }}"{% endif %}>{{ item.text }}{% if item.isActive %} <span class="sr-only">(page courante)</span>{% endif %}</a>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Do you need the redirect? Or is this like a navigation where you want the current page highlighted in the nav?

Comment: I want the navlink 'home' to be red for example when the user click on it, of corse it will be redirected to the home page, but in my case, the use is redirected to the concerned page but the link was not changed.Actually, i need to add some 'active' class on the 'home' link when user is in the home page. Same as in this : https://codepen.io/gearmobile/pen/bByZdG but for me, the page reload..

Comment: Could you also post the html code for the navigation?

Comment: please check my code, i edited it

Comment: Hello, any idea please ? :/